# Drivers suddenly stopped working for Xubuntu 16.4

Tags: drivers, xubuntu

I have a PC running Xubuntu 16.4 on a partition, I have Windows XP on the other partition. I haven't used this PC in about a month and when I came back to it I found that the driver for the WiFi and sound had stopped working. From the network connections app, it seems to connect to WiFi on startup and then refuse to connect again. The sound driver doesn't work either, no input or output and I primarily use this PC to record my music. Everything works fine on my Windows partition but I can't record in that for a few reasons or browse much of the internet as chrome no longer receives security updates. I was using Xubuntu to get around these problems.

Comment: Hello and welcome to AskUbuntu! Care to share a bit more info about your setup? What WiFi and sound card are installed?